# Удалить одинаковые записи из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблица: `tbl1`:

```
id - AUTO INCREMENT
text - varchar
```

Каким образом удалить одинаковые записи из этой таблицы, но при этом чтобы осталась только одна, например, есть 10 записей **Красная шапочка** , значит нужно удалить 9 таких записей, чтобы одна осталась.

имя записи которое может быть одинаковым записано в столбце `contents`

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: ток там surname убрать.